# Add wordpress visual editor to site pages

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to add wp visual editor to some page using php code? Of course I know how to add smth to page, but have no idea how to display visual editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output a visual editor on any page using:

```
<?php wp_editor( '', 'editor-id' ); ?>
```

Full usage info can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

Comment: Pleased I could help :)