# simple html site to wordpress and edit visually

Tags: wordpress

I am converting a very simple html site to WordPress. I made a very simple folder like,

custom_theme

header.php

front-page.php

about.php

footer.php

I cut all the code from index.html and spared them into header,footer,front-page,about.

then in the wp dash board i created those page and select the template. The site is working fine.This is the live site
http://www.mannmechanicalhvac.com/

Now i want to edit the content and image from wordpress visually not from code. Is their any possibility to do that?

@@@thanks in advance.

Comment: you have migrated but all the content is still coming from static pages. u need to create new page through CMS and paste content their also take care of template.and then include them nto menu bar

Comment: Visual Editing is possible only when you use plugins such as Visual Composer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add wordpress visual editor to site pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482579/add-wordpress-visual-editor-to-site-pages)

Comment: I tried visual composer. but it didn't work. When i pressed edit with visual composer then visual composer loading but nothing else without loading :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A very basic example:**

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <div class="page-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

[`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) outputs the content which was entered in the editor.

---

This is a good starter theme: [_s from Automattic](https://github.com/Automattic/_s)

or: http://underscores.me/

---

Recommend to read:

- [Stepping_into_Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_into_Templates)
- [Theme_Development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)
- [Template_Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags)
- [template-hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)
- [The_Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)